# Responsive Google Analytic Charts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, responsive-design, google-visualization, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I get my charts to be Bootstrap Responsive?

You can see here, that none of them are resizing properly

[image]

I have tried setting the `width` to 100%, but it does not seem to follow...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    var chart, data, options;
    function drawChart() {
        data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
              ['Day', 'Views', 'Visits', 'Bounces'],
                <?php
                    foreach($rArr as $key => $value){
                        echo '["'.$key.'", '.$this->DefaultNumber($value[0]).', '.$this->DefaultNumber($value[1]).', '.$this->DefaultNumber($value[2]).'],';
                    }
                ?>
            ]);
        options = {
                width: '100%',
                height: <?php echo $height; ?>, 
                title: '<?php echo $this->initialstartdate; ?><?php echo ' - '.$this->initialenddate; ?>',
                titleTextStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Calibri', 
                        fontSize: '14'},
                colors:['#333','#999', '#ccc'],
                backgroundColor: {fill: '#F5F5F5', opacity: 100},
                areaOpacity: 0.1,
                hAxis: {textPosition: 'in', 
                    showTextEvery: <?php echo $dateGap; ?>, 
                    slantedText: false, 
                    textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Calibri', 
                        fontSize: '12'}},
                vAxis: {textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Calibri', 
                        fontSize: '12'}},
                pointSize: 5,
                legend: { position: 'bottom',textStyle: {color: 'black', fontName: 'Calibri', 
                        fontSize: '12'}},
                isStacked: false
            };
        chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $divId; ?>'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
```

## Wrapping Code

```
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h4>Visits vs. Views vs. Bounces</h4>
            <div id="v-chart"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i initially thought that by adding a class `.block{display:block;}` would do the trick... as well as adding a height to the parent containers...  but no dice

Comment: Do you happen to have a working demo for us to work with? We can't create one with the code you provided

Comment: not yet I don't.  It's going into a CMS I'm building, so it's currently password protected, etc...   tonight or tomorrow I'll setup a `test` page for them though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is to redraw the Google visualization. Add the following line at the end of your `drawChart` function.

```
window.onresize = function(){chart.draw(data, options);};
```

I also don't use the `width` and `height` attributes when drawing the charts. I just omit them and the charts will be scaled to fit into your target div, so you just need to scale the div correctly using css. You still need to redraw if the div changes size though.

**Example**

[Here is an example of this working](http://jsbin.com/IKuDIhAs/1/quiet). Try to open this and resize the window. The chart should redraw and update it's size to cover all window.

Comment: I think this is just about there.  However, the window.onresize does not seem to be firing (at least not on all cylinders).  If I resize the browser down, nothing happens, however, now when I refresh the page, the graphs are resized.

Comment: From what you describe this doesn't look good. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: I suspect that the div is not actually shrinking when the window shrinks because your browser won't render it smaller than its contents.  Try specifying "overflow: hidden" on the chart's container div's css.

Comment: The div should be shrinking just fine, it's a bootstrap col-xs-6 div container